Screenshot of the game using PrintWindow
I need a way to photograph a game window (programmatically in C#) that can be hidden behind other windows or be inactive. I try to use PrintWindow for this, but all I get is the frame of the game window. The game itself is not visible. Please help me if anyone knows what's going on.
internal static class Screenshot
 {
     [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
     internal struct RECT
     {
         public int Left;
         public int Top;
         public int Right;
         public int Bottom;
     }

     [DllImport("user32.dll")]
     public static extern bool PrintWindow(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hdcBlt, uint nFlags);

     [DllImport("user32.dll")]
     public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

     [DllImport("user32.dll")]
     private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

     public static Bitmap CaptureGameProcess( string windowTitle, string screenShotSavePath)
     {
         IntPtr handle = FindWindow(null, windowTitle);

         // Get the dimensions of the window
         RECT rect;
         GetWindowRect(handle, out rect);

         int width = rect.Right - rect.Left;
         int height = rect.Bottom - rect.Top;

         // Create a bitmap to store the screenshot
         Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

         // Capture the window
         using (Graphics gfxBmp = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
         {
             IntPtr hdcBitmap = gfxBmp.GetHdc();
             PrintWindow(handle, hdcBitmap, 0);
             gfxBmp.ReleaseHdc(hdcBitmap);
         }

         return bmp;
     }
    }

Amazon Adventure - There is a frame here

Oxygen Not Included - It's just a white image here

A screenshot of the Half-Life game returns just a black window.

Yes you are capturing the window.  What you are not capturing is the DirectX or OpenGL etc. graphics window that is inside and not part of the pixels of the main windows. I have not done this in a while but it is something along the lines of Get the HWND, then GetDC, then BitBlt and that gets you the bitmap.

...why are people still using GDI-based functions like PrintWindow? Windows switched to the DWM back in 2006 when Vista came out... I suggest you see how it's done today.

Are you sure that the game even responds to the WM_PRINT message? It's possible that the game basically ignores the message. In the case of Amazon Adventure, the window base class renders the frame. This is just speculation.

@RichardKeene
Thanks, this method works, but only for old games. I'll try use newer methods.

@Dai
You're right, I think I need to try newer methods. Since the method proposed above captures only old games. In new games, a screenshot of the editor is displayed instead of the game content :-)

DwmRegisterThumbnail -> DwmUpdateThumbnailProperties (the rcSource and rcDestination members of the DWM_THUMBNAIL_PROPERTIES struct define the size of the capture - note that the capture is dynamic, i.e., the thumbnail is rendered live onto the destination's surface). DwmUnregisterThumbnail() after

Many of the modern games actually try to prevent screen shots of the game in order to stop AI or auto-aim from working. Keeps the cheaters out. That may be what is happening on the newer games.
